# How to get blob data as byte array type in android with ksoap?

Tags: android, arrays, blob, ksoap

I have a web service and I reach it with ksoap library in my android application. My code is given below;

Data.java

```
public class Data implements KvmSerializable{

public byte[] byteValue;

public Data(){

}

public Data(byte[] byteValue) {
    this.byteValue = byteValue;
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch(arg0) {
        case 0:
            return byteValue;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object o) {
    switch (index) {  
        case 0:
            byteValue = (byte[]) o;
            break;        
    }
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {

    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            info.type = MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS;
            info.name = "byteValue";
            break;        
    }

}
```

There is a blob value in my database **different from the** **image**. When I use following code,

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
response.getProperty(0);
```

I get object type value, but for my android application I need to get this value as byte[] type.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right solution for my application.

In my activity class, i tried below code :

```
byte[] byteValue = Base64.decode(response.getProperty(0).toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```